# What sql formula am I missing?

Tags: sql, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I need to find out the busiest location by check in for a query.

```
select name
from checkin join location on checkin.locid = location.LocID
order by name
```

This query gives me the result but I cannot figure how to group it by numbers.
If I put count (distinct name) it gives a weird result and if I group by name it does not give me the numbers

I am trying to group the names and the amount of times it has come in two separate columns?

[image: Locations]

Comment: Will you explain more details exactly what you want to do. and table schema.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select name , count(checkinpk)
.....
group by name , count(checkinpk)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly what I am looking.

Comment: aggregate function will not work in group by clause.

Comment: SQl server do support group by aggregate functions

https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-group-by/

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
select name, COUNT(C.LocID) as Checkin_Count
from location AS L
inner join checkin as C on C.LocID= L.LocID
group by name
order by COUNT(C.LocID) desc
```